# remove last n characters of a file using batch

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, file-io, batch-processing

I am having around 500 files in a folder. I am trying to concatenate a 4KB data(stored as a file) to all the files 
using batch "`for /r %i in (*) do type 4KB file.txt >> %i`

Now I want them to revert to orignal state. Few files are around 14GB . While trying to read , it takes a lot of time to open.

Please let me know how can I revert them back to original state.

Comment: Can you give some examples on the contents of these files and what you would like to have removed? Or the state how it's now and what you want to see as result.

Comment: Most of them are binary files. the 4 KB file is a text file which I want to add them to test upload speed taken for every 4KB added. It can be anything of our wish .

Comment: Just make a backup of all files in a different folder before concatenate the 4KB data, and delete original folder and rename the backup one when you want to revert to original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the difficulty of this task depends on the actual string you appended to the file.

```
Get-ChildItem [your path here] | ForEach-Object {
$TempVar = Get-Content $_ | Select-string -Exclude "Something that uniquely matches the string you want to remove"
$TempVar | Set-Content $_ }
```

Alternatively:

```
Get-ChildItem [your path here] | ForEach-Object {
$Length = ($_.ToCharArray) - 4096 #As you have 4KB, exactly?
$Newfile = ($_.ToCharArray() | Select -first $Length) -join ""
$NewFile | Set-content $_ 

}
```

Both attempts can be considered harmful as this may affect encoding, file structure etc - I just don't have enough time to check on that. If the files are of any importance, better back them up.